# (LKM char device drivers ) Simple Linux Kernel Module Read and write from userspace to kernelspace

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neQHx.png)** sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog

**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfK7W.png)** userspace program output.

Unable to write and read to kernel space module using userspace program.

I think that `copy_to_user` function is returning 0 which means but actually nothing is copied.

I am using derekmolloy example but is not working at all (Ubuntu LTS 16.04.1)

Second think that I want to ask how can i print this. char* buffer dev_read function because when I want to print this using printk the the module got killed.

```
dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
```

ebbchar.c (LKM)

```
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
      int error_count = 0;

      error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, message, size_of_message);

     if (error_count==0)
     {            // if true then have success
        printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Sent %d characters to the user\n", 
               size_of_message);
         return (size_of_message=0);  // clear the position to the 
                                      //start and 
       return 0;
     }
    else
   {
      printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Failed to send %d characters to the 
             user\n", error_count);
      return -EFAULT;  // Failed -- return a bad address message (i.e. 
                       //-14)
   }
}


static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t 
                       len, loff_t *offset)
{

      int error; 
      // sprintf(message, "%c", buffer, len);   // appending received 
                                            //string with its length
     error = copy_to_user(message, buffer , size_of_message);
   //ssize_t simple_read_from_buffer(void *to, size_t count, loff_t 
   //*ppos, const void *from, size_t available)
  //  error = simple_read_from_buffer(&message, 256, offset , buffer , 
                                     // len);

     int i = 0; 

     printk (KERN_INFO "KERNEL-SPACE copying copy_to_user() %d",error 

    size_of_message = strlen(message);                              
    printk ( KERN_INFO "KERNEL-SPACE size of message recivied is %d \n 
            ", size_of_message);

    for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i ++)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "KERNEL-SPACE message[%d]=%s \n" , i , 
        message[i] );
    }

        printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Received %zu characters from the 
        user the message is %s\n", len, message);


    return len;
}
```

user-space program

```
int main()
{
   int ret, 
   int fd;
   char stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH];


   fd = open("/dev/ebbchar", O_RDWR);// Open the device with 

    if (fd < 0)
    {
       perror("USER-SPACE : Failed to open the device...");
       return errno;
    }

   for (int i = 0 ; i < BUFFER_LENGTH ; i++)
   {
       stringToSend[i] = 'a';
   }    

   printf(" USER-SPACE : Writing message to the device [%s].\n", 
           stringToSend);

   ret = write(fd, stringToSend, BUFFER_LENGTH); // Send the string to 
                                                 //the LKM
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      perror(" USER-SPACE : Failed to write the message to the 
               device.");
      return errno;
   }

   printf("USER-SPACE : Press ENTER to read back from the 
                   device...\n");
   getchar();

   printf("USER-SPACE : Reading from the device...\n");
   ret = read(fd, receive, BUFFER_LENGTH); // Read the response from 
                                           // the LKM
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      perror("USER-SPACE : Failed to read the message from the 
            device.");
      return errno;
   }
    printf("USER-SPACE : The received message is: [%s]\n", receive);
    printf("USER-SPACE : End of the program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**The out-put of user-space program**

sudo ./a.out
USER-SPACE : Starting device test code example...
 USER-SPACE : Writing message to the device [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa��� �].
USER-SPACE : Press ENTER to read back from the device...

USER-SPACE : Reading from the device...
USER-SPACE : The received message is: []
USER-SPACE : End of the program
river@mystic-computer:~$ ^C

**The output  of sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog**

Feb  8 22:11:05 mystic-computer kernel: [21689.104780] EBBChar: Device successfully closed
Feb  8 22:12:15 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895624] EBBChar: Device has been opened 2 time(s)
Feb  8 22:12:15 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895674] KERNEL-SPACE copying copy_to_user() 0
Feb  8 22:12:24 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895678] KERNEL-SPACE size of message recivied is 0 KERNEL-SPACE message[0]=KERNEL-SPACE message[116]=KERNEL-SPACE message[152]=KERNEL-SPACE message[154]=<6>[21767.721994] EBBChar: Sent 0 characters to the user
Feb  8 22:12:24 mystic-computer kernel: [21767.722145] EBBChar: Device successfully closed
Feb  8 22:13:08 mystic-computer kernel: [21812.346367] EBBChar: Goodbye from the LKM!
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177728] EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177743] EBBChar: registered correctly with major number 243
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177773] EBBChar: device class registered correctly
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177943] EBBChar: device class created correctly
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080308] EBBChar: Device has been opened 1 time(s)
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080649] KERNEL-SPACE copying copy_to_user() 0
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080654] KERNEL-SPACE size of message recivied is 0 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080654]  <6>[21844.080660] KERNEL-SPACE message[0]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:11:05 mystic-computer kernel: [21689.104780] EBBChar: Device successfully closed
Feb  8 22:12:15 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895624] EBBChar: Device has been opened 2 time(s)
Feb  8 22:12:15 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895674] KERNEL-SPACE copying copy_to_user() 0
Feb  8 22:12:24 mystic-computer kernel: [21758.895678] KERNEL-SPACE size of message recivied is 0 KERNEL-SPACE message[0]=KERNEL-SPACE message[116]=KERNEL-SPACE message[152]=KERNEL-SPACE message[154]=<6>[21767.721994] EBBChar: Sent 0 characters to the user
Feb  8 22:12:24 mystic-computer kernel: [21767.722145] EBBChar: Device successfully closed
Feb  8 22:13:08 mystic-computer kernel: [21812.346367] EBBChar: Goodbye from the LKM!
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177728] EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177743] EBBChar: registered correctly with major number 243
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177773] EBBChar: device class registered correctly
Feb  8 22:13:25 mystic-computer kernel: [21829.177943] EBBChar: device class created correctly
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080308] EBBChar: Device has been opened 1 time(s)
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080649] KERNEL-SPACE copying copy_to_user() 0
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080654] KERNEL-SPACE size of message recivied is 0 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.080654]  <6>[21844.080660] KERNEL-SPACE message[0]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081224] KERNEL-SPACE message[247]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081226] KERNEL-SPACE message[248]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081228] KERNEL-SPACE message[249]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081230] KERNEL-SPACE message[250]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081233] KERNEL-SPACE message[251]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081235] KERNEL-SPACE message[252]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081237] KERNEL-SPACE message[253]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081239] KERNEL-SPACE message[254]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081242] KERNEL-SPACE message[255]=(null) 
Feb  8 22:13:40 mystic-computer kernel: [21844.081245] EBBChar: Received 256 characters from the user the message is

Comment: In short: On success, `.read` function should return number of bytes successfully read (which has been written into user-space buffer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH atlast !! Figured out the. Actually the dev_write was not working because the memory (static char[256] *message) was not acquired using kmalloc

message  = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);

Any one facing this problem can use kmalloc. To acquire memory in kernel space. You can kmalloc in __init or dev_write functions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but you need to terminate stringToSend array with NULL character, ie, stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH - 1] = '\0'

Otherwise,

printf("USER-SPACE : The received message is: [%s]\n", receive);

does not work correctly, because printf() does not know where string terminates without NULL char.

At least fix this to make print out correct.

Comment: No.               I use message = kmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);